# Submit <a> href to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I don't know if this is possible but any help given will be appreciated.

I normally submit my html forms to external php scripts using javascript.
The reson being the javascript handles showing error notifications in a nice way.

Below is an example;

```
<script>
    $("input#submit").click(function() {
        $('#loader').show();
        // Client side validation
        if ($("#category").val() == "") {
            $('#loader').hide();
            detError();
        } else {
            $.post($("#cat-form").attr("action"),
                $("#cat-form :input").serializeArray(),

                function(response) {
                    switch (response) {
                        case "Valid":
                            $('#loader').hide();
                            catSuccess();
                            $('#cat-form').trigger("reset");
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                window.location.href = "blog_admin_categories.php";
                            }, 4000);
                            break;
                        case "not Valid":
                            $('#loader').hide();
                            catError();
                            break;
                    }
                });
        }
        $("#cat-form").submit(function() {
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, based on the response I receive from the echo in the `PHP` script (valid, not Valid etc) I run another function and maybe refresh the page.

Now I want to do this with a link `<a>`.

```
<a class='link' id='delete-link' href=/blog/php/blog_category_delete.php?delete='$cat_id'>Delete</a>
```

How can I do this?

With the help of answers below, i now have this working...
Code below;

```
<script>
                $("a.delete").click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault(); // this is needed to stop the browser from changing the site
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');

                    $.post($(this).attr('href'),
                           $('href').serializeArray(),

                           function(response) {
                        switch(response) {
                            case "Valid":
                                $('#loader').hide();
                                catDeleted();
                                $('#cat-form').trigger("reset");
                                setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="blog_admin_categories.php";},3000);
                                break;}
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want your delete to do a similar post and get a similar response?

Comment: just put a .click() handler on the `<a>`, exactly as you're doing for the form's submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your href has broken quotations.

```
<a class='jslink' href='blog/php/blog_category_delete.php?delete=$cat_id'>Delete</a>
<script>
    $("a.jslink").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // this is needed to stop the browser from changing the site
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        // your code
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.

How do I create a function similar to the one a form uses to pass to the php script?
Can you give me an idea of how the function will look like?
I just want to catch the echo returned from the php script.
As you can see from my code, I can do this for forms.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Star!

Comment: If you don't need to post information to the script, a simple [ajax get-request](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) will suffice:  

`$.get(href, '', function (data) { /* what you want to do with the data /* });`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by AJAX.

```
$("#delete-link").click(function(){

    //you can write your ajax here 

    return false;
});
```

Comment: this click handler solution is way more elegant than my onclick attribute solution.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the `href` attribute of the `<a>` just create and `onclick` attribute that can call your javascript function:

```
<a class='link' id='delete-link' href="" onclick="callphp('$cat_id')">Delete</a>

<script> 
  function callphp( value ) {
    //call you submission function and do your validation here...  
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how the function will look like?
I just want to catch the echo returned from the php script.
As you can see from my code, I can do this for forms.

Comment: You should be able to use your original submit function... Everything within the click handler function.

Comment: Based on my function for submitting a form,

`$.post($("#cat-form").attr("action"),
 $("#cat-form :input").serializeArray()`

How will I replace these two?
One is passing the action which is post, the other is gathering the data of the form.

Answer (score 0):

jquery is the simplest way. Attach the click listener to the link using jquery like this :

```
 $("#mylink").click(fucnction(){     });
```

and inside the curly brackets you can $.post or $.get to send AJAX request to the php script